# Concurrency problems updating another's collection stats

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, concurrency

I'm trying to make a notation system for movies

A user can note a Movie in their List.

Whenever the user clicks on the frontend, the `listId, movieId, note` are sent to the server to update the note. The note can be set to null, but it does not remove the entry from the list.

But if the user clicks too much times, the movie's `totalNote` and `nbNotes` are completely broken. Feels like there is some sort of concurrency problems ?

Is this the correct approach to this problem or am I updating in a wrong way ?

The mongoose schemas related :

```
// Movie Schema
const movieSchema = new Schema({
    // ...
    note: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    totalNotes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    nbNotes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
})
movieSchema.statics.updateTotalNote = function (movieId, oldNote, newNote) {
    if (!oldNote && !newNote) return
    const nbNotes = !newNote ? -1 : (!oldNote ? 1 : 0) // If oldNote is null we +1, if newNote is null we -1
    return Movie.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: movieId }, { $inc: { nbNotes: nbNotes, totalNotes: (newNote - oldNote) } }, { new: true }).catch(err => console.error("Couldn't update note from movie", err))
}

// List Schema
const movieEntry = new Schema({
    _id: false, // movie makes an already unique attribute, which is populated on GET
    movie: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movies', required: true },
    note: { type: Number, default: null, max: 21 },
})

const listSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users', required: true },
    movies: [movieEntry]
})
```

The server update API (add / Remove movieEntry are similar with `$push` and `$pull` instead of `$set`)

```
exports.updateEntry = (req, res) => {
    const { listId, movieId } = req.params
    const movieEntry = { movieId: movieId, note: req.body.note }
    List.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: listId, 'movies.movie': movieId }, { $set: { 'movies.$[elem]': movieEntry } }, { arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.movie': movieId }] })
        .exec()
        .then(list => {
            if (!list) return res.sendStatus(404)
            const oldNote = list.getMovieEntryById(movieId).note // getMovieEntryById(movieId) = return this.movies.find(movieEntry => movieEntry.movie == movieId)
            Movie.updateTotalNote(movieId, oldNote, movieEntry.note)
            let newList = list.movies.find(movieEntry => movieEntry.movie == movieId) // Because I needed the oldNote and findOneAndUpdate returns the list prior to modification, I change it to return it
            newList.note = movieEntry.note
            newList.status = movieEntry.status
            newList.completedDate = movieEntry.completedDate
            return res.status(200).json(list)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
            return res.sendStatus(400)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entries I needed to update were arrays that could grow indefinitely so I had to first change my models and use virtuals and another model for the the list entries.

Doing so made the work easier and I was able to create, update and delete the entries more easily and without any concurrency problems.

This might also not have been a concurrency problem in the first place, but a transaction problem.